# LIS3MDL sensor Vehicle Detection range

Tags: sensor, arm, magnetometer

I want to use LIS3MDL magnetoresistive sensor for Parking Vehicle Detection project. I compared this with HMC5883L. LIS3MDL 's Full Scale range is +16 Gauss but HMC5883L 8 Gauss.

But I did not understand what is detection range. Do you know anything about it ?
Can these sensors detect vehicle from 1meter.

Comment: They detect magnetic fields, if the magnetic field changes then they can detect it. It varies from vehicle to vehicle

Answer (score 0):

The earth's magnetic field is about 0.3 to 0.6 Gauss.  You will be looking for changes in the local field due to the presence of magnetic material (steel); probably in the tens of milliGauss.  Get the most sensitive one that you can.